# How to prevent a certain textured quad from the effect of the pixel Shader at the run time in slimdxdirect3d9 or directx9?

Tags: directx, slimdx, video

I am having a video and and image slide show being rendered simultaneously. Both video and the image is being rendered by the help of texture and two different quads. Video is being rendered on the whole screen but the image of the slide show is being rendered along the video on some particular area of the screen. I am using pixel shader to give effects in my slide show but the pixel shader is affecting both the textures being rendered that is my video and the image slide show. But I want it to give effect only to the image slide show. For this I am doing Device.PixelShader=null when the video quad is being drawn but giving my pixel shader to the device when the the image is being drawn. But I want to know that is there any other way that can prevent my video quad from the effect pf the pixel shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's what you are supposed to do. When you use a shader, it stays bound yo the graphics card until you set a new one, so unselect it when you don't want it to be applied.